# Piwik Dashboard Segmentation Issue

Tags: php, analytics, matomo

I'm trying to figure out how to pass in segmentation params to filter out results in the 'Dashboard' for specific custom variables we're storing in the db - but just haven't found the right solution.

This is what I've got as my src for the iframe:

```
http://www.domain.com/piwik/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&moduleToWidgetize=Dashboard&actionToWidgetize=index&idSite=<?=cstPIWIKSITE?>&period=week&date=yesterday&segment=customVariableName4==<?=$key1?>;customVariableValue4==<?=$value1?>;customVariableName5==<?=$key2?>;customVariableValue5==<?=$value2?>
```

The scope of the custom variables is set to "visit" and I've ensured that the data is indeed being stored in log_visit in the fourth and fifth custom var fields.

This issue is that there is this message on every widget = "There is no data for this report."

Conversely, when I remove the segment params from the src above, I do indeed get results. However, I need this to be segmented out as different divisions should be able to mine their own analytics.

In case you need this info:
Piwik Version: 1.9
This is a standalone PHP site (not utilizing WP, Joomla, etc.)
'Anonymous' has 'VIEW' access
From global.ini.php = anonymous_user_enable_use_segments_API = 1

Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Experiencing the exact same issue. I just updated mh Piwik installation from 1.8.2 (where the segment had no effect at all) to 1.9.1, and now the segment just removes all data from the dashboard. The same segment works if I just apply it to a widget.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Piwik <= 1.9.1, where the dashboard is empty if more than one segment is used.

Here's a forum thread with others who have experiencedd the same thing (towards the bottom of the thread):

http://forum.piwik.org/read.php?2,92057,96203